# A simple geometric proof of Zariski's connectedness theorem?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

By *Zariski's connectedness theorem*, we will mean the following: Let $f : X \to Y$ be a proper map between irreducible normal varieties (over $\mathbb{C}$) with $f_{\ast} \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$. Then $f$ is surjective and the fibers of $f$ are connected.

A proof is given [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/ZMTfull.pdf) The proof seems to use quite heavy machinery and is not very enlightening from a geometric point of view. Is there a simple geometric proof that the fibers of an algebraic fiber space are connected?

Lazarsfeld's first book gives the following proof: Any projective morphism $g : V \to W$ of irreducible varieties admits a Stein factorization, i.e., $g = a \circ b$, where $a$ is an algebraic fiber space and $b$ is a finite map. In particular, $g$ is a fiber space if and only if the finite part of its Stein factorization is trivial. In particular, all the fibers are connected.

The implication of not being finite $\implies$ fibers are connected is not clear to me.